# When to restart Sensu

Tags: monitoring, sensu

When must the sensu-client be restarted? I've noticed that I can just restart the sensu-api and sensu-server and new checks that I add seem to work. Do I need to restart clients like the doc says?

Comment: We need to restart the sensu-client only if any configuration changes is done on client system so that the new configuration are loaded and the new new changes may take effect. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is no. You only have to restart clients when adding new configurations to them. Otherwise they'll automatically pick up new checks that the server dictates.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part configuration management tools will restart the right components when necessary.

The clients *do* need to be restarted when client-side configuration (standalone checks, rabbitmq, etc) changes.

Also, the servers themselves need their local clients restarted (if you are running a sensu client on your sensu server too), even when server-side definitions are changed, due to this bug:
https://github.com/sensu/sensu/issues/806